# Calling GetParent() on root drive

Tags: c#

`C:` is my PC's boot drive.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo;
dirInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"C:"); // Case 1
dirInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"C:\"); // Case 2
```

Case 1:

`dirInfo` is not null and `dirInfo.FullPath` is set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7" on my machine

Case 2:

`dirInfo` is null

From [Directory.GetParent Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx):

> null if path is the root directory

"C:" is not treated as root. Why not?

Comment: Because it isn't a folder at all? Although I'd expect an exception from this

Comment: Ever since the days of MS-DOS, `cd C:` means change the directory to whatever is the current directory on the C: drive.

Comment: For DOS, maybe. For commands that expect paths or volumes this is true. `GetParent` though expects a path and returns an absolute path. `C:`  isn't a valid path rooted path, so it's treated as a relative path, just as `Directory.GetParent("c")` or `Directory.GetParent("a")`. For all these cases, the parent directory is the current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directory.GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a string manipulation function that takes an absolute or relative local path or a UNC and returns an absolute string. If the path is relative, the current working directory is used. As the documentation explains:

> The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to, but not including, the last DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar.

This means that if you passed `c\` , the method would return `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\c`.

`C:` is a volume letter, not a path. Since `C:` isn't recognized as an absolute path or a UNC path, it's treated as a relative path, just like `c` , `a` or `nosuchfolder`. In both cases, the return value will be the current working directory. When debugging with Visual Studio, the working directory is Visual Studio's directory.